# Abbreviation for "in contrast to"

Tags: abbreviations

We have abbreviation for 'that is'-i.e., 'for example'-e.g., 'confer'-c.f., 'versus'-vs.

In my understanding, i.e. and e.g. is commonly used inside a sentence, while c.f. and vs. is used outside a sentence, e.g. inside a bracket. (Correct me on this)

> "These models are called feedworard, in contrast to recurrent neural networks, because information flows through the function evaluated from x."

I see a lot of usage for 'in contrast to' (probably as much as i.e.), but never seen an abbreviation for it. Is there any abbreviation for 'in contrast to' (where you can use commonly put inside a sentence)?

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the abbreviation for "in contrast to" would be used? I wonder why you need it and when.

Comment: @Rathony "These models are called feedworard, in contrast to recurrent neural networks, because information flows through the function evaluated from x." I see a lot of usage for 'in contrast to' (probably as much as i.e.), but never seen an abbreviation for it. Nothing important really, just my ongoing curiosity.

Comment: Please edit your question with the example sentence and note that you need to provide an example sentence whenever you ask for a single word or phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[vs or versus](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/versus) :***

> - ***Abbr. v. or vs.*** In conflict or competition with; against: the plaintiff versus the defendant; *Michigan versus Ohio State.*

(AHD)

Comment: Please refer to my edited question, I've edited it to be more specific.

Comment: @JeeSeokYoon - vs has the meaning and usage you are looking for, are you asking for an alternative?

Comment: You can find usage examples here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvs%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I wonder how "in contrast to" and "versus" are interchangeable as "in contrast to" means "in comparison with" rather than "in competition with, against, etc." That's why I asked the OP to write an example sentence where the abbreviated version would be used. "In contrast to last year's profits, the company is not doing very well." Can we use "vs" or "versus" in the sentence?

Comment: This year profits are more negative vs last year.